# Separate a long text from a SQL read in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Im currently using a gridview table so show some data using SQL. So i have read in some info and displayed them in my gridview. [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJTAx.png)

As you can se, i am displaying the path. The thing is that i only want to display the last part of the path that shows the date and how many km the car has traveled. Im using asp .net and my boundfield method looks like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ReadOutID" HeaderText="ReadOutID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ReadOutID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileTime" HeaderText="FileTime" SortExpression="FileTime" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImportTime" HeaderText="ImportTime" SortExpression="ImportTime" />
                                <asp:Boundfield DataField="FullPath" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
```

How can i just show the last part?

Comment: You might want to put that sort of logic into a model rather than you view (if you have one)?
Are you binding straight to the SQL data source?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this kind of expression into a template field

```
Text='<%# Eval("filename").ToString().Substring(0,9) %>'
```

Or you can write a function in .cs file like this.

```
protected getString(string str) { return (str..Substring(0,9)); }
```

And use this in gridview label as

```
Text='<%# getString(Eval("filename").ToString()) %>'
```

Comment: Okay, i still get a error when i insert your first code into the template field. it says " Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding event." Any ideas?

Comment: You need to change the data bound field to a template field

Comment: This sort of thing

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, but i noticed something. Since the vehicles i load has names that has a name where the length of the name varies. So is there some kind of a function to sort after a certain pattern? Lets say a pattern that writes everything after a certain amount of number?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get the question can you try to explain again?

Comment: The path for all the vehicles has a name whick looks like 
..../20160405_5000km
.../20160324_7000km
.../20150403_50230km
as you can see there is a pattern. There is always the date first and then the number of km it has traveled. So i was wondering if there is a way to sort after that pattern. Because if you use substring you can only decide after the number of letters to write out. And since the cars has different name such as bumblebee or hero the number of letters varies. So i was wondering if you can sort after the pattern i mentioned?

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting it. Could you just use the underscores?

Comment: I wrote an answer, please see below

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to simplify it:
the pathway for different cars looks like this
X:\05_General\T\TestVehicleInfo\Vehicles\Aamir_2107005\Readouts\All\20160201_474km_TMSupdate_newE2\Aamir_2107005_20160201_474km_XCOM_ALL_DTC_BMV_after.txt

X:\05_General\T\TestVehicleInfo\Vehicles\Amazonas_3859276\Readouts\All\20141218_7237km_SOP1505P3_Update\After\XCOM\Amazonas_3859276_20141218_0km_XCOM_ALL_DTC_SSBTOA.txt

The first one is for the car named aamir and the second one is for the car amazonas

I would like to write out everything from the date forward. in these two cases i would like to write out 
20160201_474km_TMSupdate_newE2\Aamir_2107005_20160201_474km_XCOM_ALL_DTC_BMV_after.txt

and

20141218_7237km_SOP1505P3_Update\After\XCOM\Amazonas_3859276_20141218_0km_XCOM_ALL_DTC_SSBTOA.txt

the first one is for aamir and the second one for amazonas. Do you understand me?

Comment: Edit your question and add this.